# Did Einstein say something about stress and idiots?

Tags: quotes, albert-einstein

There is this quote floating around (got it via Facebook) attributed to Albert Einstein:

> „Der Hauptgrund für Stress ist der tägliche Kontakt mit Idioten.“

Which I would translate to:

> The main reason for stress is the daily contact with idiots.

Now it struck me rather odd that he would have said that, and doing a short research I couldn't find a quote with a source.

So I fired up Google Trends and there is a sudden rise in August 2016, before that date the words I would search that quote with have almost no hits. "Einstein Stress" produces results because there is the stress energy tensor in English.

Comment: Where on Facebook?

Comment: @Brythan it was part of [Spasseshalber](https://www.facebook.com/Spasseshalber/) a page with jokes, but it is rather widespread if you search for it.

Comment: Posting a "joke" to the Internet is a good way to start "false news".

Comment: Welcome to the site.  The question needs to include a notable source for the claim, some widely read source that asserts (not as an obvious joke) that he actually said this.  A Facebook group isn't enough.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you - I'm afraid I cannot find a source which would qualify as notable then. So this question should probably be closed. I've seen other questions like this, so I thought it would be okay.

Comment: I’ve found a non-English page that seems to mention this though I haven’t tried running it through google translate to see if it’s talking about this quote, or to see how notable the example is: http://www.fischbild.de/wordpress/der-hauptgrund-fuer-stress-ist-der-taegliche-kontakt-mit-idioten-albert-einstein-zitat/ . Ironically, the biggest problem I had, while googling for Einstein idiots, was another bogus Einstein quote about technology making us idiots, which was rather self-fulfilling.

Comment: Does a [product you can buy on Amazon](https://www.amazon.de/Albert-Einstein-Hauptgrund-Idioten-Blechschild/dp/B074PSDBH7) count as a notable source? And then there is this [blog entry](http://www.diemitdemrotenlippenstift.com/lifehacks-fuer-den-umgang-mit-idioten/), but that blog has a lower Alexa score than my own - so probably not very notable either.

Comment: the following German blog strongly suggests (based on google n-grams) that Einstein didn't say the above phrase: https://www.arsenal-of-wisdom.org/?p=964

Answer (score 6):

Bad news: it is most likely not. There are first references 2005 and "Einstein" was associated with about 3 years later and even used on book covers.
It never was found in any of Einstein's digitized texts or work of references.

I also came here through google when searching for this quote and also found a blog about false quotes
(use Translator for German)
http://falschzitate.blogspot.com/2018/12/der-hauptgrund-fur-stress-ist-der.html

Comment: I don't know how this is bad news, thanks for that link, which I hadn't found.

Comment: I liked the idea he said this :-)